# Hybrid bike for speed

Tags: hybrid-bike

I am looking for a speedy hybrid bike with skinny tires. I am 6 foot tall. Please suggest me some good bike under **$800**. I don't want road bike since I am not very much comfortable riding a road bike but I wanna match speed. Please share your thoughts.

Comment: Shopping recommendations are off-topic here, but here are some tips: A hybrid has higher drag than a road bike so is inherently slower for the same effort.  You might be able to keep up especially on shorter rides but you'll have to work at it.  I don't like drop bars in traffic and don't ride much open road so I ride a GT traffic hybrid (a few years old, probably just out of your budget new) on 28mm marathon plus tyres. I get decent speeds out of it even with panniers (e.g. 48 miles in 4 hours include map and food stops, sustained 20mph on a flat road).

Comment: $800 is a lot - consider a decent used bike instead.

Answer (score 2):

I think the name is now a "Fitness bike". These will have straight handlebars. At $800, you are close to the high end of the spectrum on these bikes at a store. These are made for the casual cyclist (1-5 miles) that wants something better than a Walmart bike to get around town. They are in an upright position, but usually the frames are pretty heavy and the shifting components are rather heavy too.

A "touring bike" will have drop bars be in a more upright position than a road bike. I think it might be a good option for you. For $800, you will be close to the lowest end of the spectrum. You will have quite a bit of shopping to do. These are made for people going on LONG rides (> 100 miles) that carry their food and shelter with them (well, maybe the high end bikes are). They are in a more upright position than for road cyclists who have team cars following them with all their repair equipment.

The difference in weight might not make you go slower, but the difference in the aero position will.

Remember, you have quite a few extra purchases to make on your first bike:
Lock, helmet, lights, water bottle cages, water bottles, saddle bag + on road repair items, home pump, pump to carry on rides. These can easily add up to close to $200.

Shop around a few local bike shops and see what they have. So long as the wheels have Schrader valves, you should be able to put on a smaller tires on your own.

Do the usual shopping tricks: 
- Ask if they have last year's model
- Ask if anybody returned anything they are looking to resell (many buy a bike, and find it too scary to ride on the streets and return it within the allowable time)
- Look for used bikes on your favorite site.

Comment: Good work for avoiding a specific product suggestion in your answer.

Comment: Cant's seem to find a connection between valve type and ability to change tires. What's wrong with presta?

Comment: I have no idea why I mentionned Schrader valves. Presta valves need the consumer to be more "informed" but they are fine. I use them on my bikes. By informed, I mean you have to unscrew it to allow air in and out.